# Commercial app with optional GPL software usage

Tags: gpl, lgpl

Say one develops a closed source app that can produce a file of its own format like .ll .Then one asks the user to run a GPL licenced batch script that uses ffmpeg(GPL) to do the final bit. Note that ffmpeg or the batch script is not distributed with the software but install instructions are there in the software. Will the software have to be GPL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use/distribute LGPL command line software in mine that isn't LGPL?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/can-i-use-distribute-lgpl-command-line-software-in-mine-that-isnt-lgpl)

Comment: No as the program itself is not calling exec nor am I distributing it. Let me tell you the process again.Say my app produces an output.ll file. The user optionally downloads the batch file and ffmpeg separately the runs the bat file to get ffmpegoutput.mp4

Comment: Should that app be LGPL or GPL?

Answer (score 3):

> Will the software have to be GPL?

That depends on how closely your software depends on the post-processing by ffmpeg in particular.

If ffmpeg is just one of potentially many (independently developed) programs that can read and process the files your app creates, then your app is a separate and independent work from ffmpeg as far as copyright is concerned and that means both works can be licensed completely independently.

If your app uses intimate knowledge of how ffmpeg works and uses this file format to communicate complex, ffmpeg-specific data structures, then most likely your app will be considered a derived work of ffmpeg and needs to be under the GPL itself as well.

The question as to who invokes ffmpeg (the app itself or the user of the app) I find less relevant. Just the fact that it is two executables is relevant for the determination if the GPL applies.

Comment: Basically if it is an app that can make gifs and due to some reason making mp4 is not possible so the user is instructed to make mp4 using ffmpeg using a batch file.

Comment: @compenthusiast, that is two independent programs then. One that creates animated GIFs (which can be used in their own right) and a second one that can convert an animated GIF into an MP4. That matches the first case I outlined.

Comment: I know it should be understood but many people fear one mistake and GPL will release their source.

Comment: @compenthusiast IANAL, but when you read the GPL, the main consequence of violating it seems to be that you lose all rights given to you by that license. That in itself doesn't necessarily mean you'll be forced to release the source. What it *does* mean however, is that you're no longer allowed to copy, modify or distribute the covered work. In addition to that, the original author could potentially sue you for copyright infringement.

Comment: What I meant was that lets say I use some GPL software in my code without noticing.The liscensor can sue me and most likely I might be ordered to apply GPL to my code thereby revealing the source to anyone who recieves it.

Comment: I think it would be more likely that instead of filing a lawsuit, they'd ask you to either comply with the GPL or else stop distributing their software (i.e. completely remove it from your code). I don't know if you could actually be *forced* to open source your code, so i guess we would need a lawyer to answer that one.